# Multiple RelativeLayout's all programmatically

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, android-relativelayout

Below is what my layout looks like.

[image]

What I want is for the 2 green arrows to be centered vertically in the top left square.  Also, the double number sign ("##") needs to be centered vertically and horizontally in the top left square.

Then, the other set of double number signs need to be centered vertically and horizontally in the top right square.

Below is the code.

```
public class Puzzle extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dividers();
        topLeft();
        topRight();

        setContentView(relativelayout);
    }

    public void topLeft() {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view0.getId());
        params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, view1.getId());
        relativelayout.addView(topLeftRL, params0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        topLeftRL.addView(puzzle, params1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        topLeftRL.addView(left, params2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        topLeftRL.addView(right, params3);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params4.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        topLeftRL.addView(levelCounter, params4);

        left.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_arrow);
        right.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_arrow);
        puzzle.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.puzzlePuzzleTV));
        levelCounter.setText("###");
    }

    public void topRight() {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view0.getId());
        params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, view1.getId());
        relativelayout.addView(topRightRL, params0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        topRightRL.addView(record, params1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        topRightRL.addView(moves, params2);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        topRightRL.addView(movesCounter, params3);

        movesCounter.setText("##");
        record.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.puzzleRecordTV) + " " + "##");
        moves.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.puzzleMovesTV));
    }

    public void dividers() {

        // vertical line (top of screen)
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(5, height / 6);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params1.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);  // left, top, right, bottom
        relativelayout.addView(view1, params1);

        // horizontal line (top of screen)
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params0 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view1.getId());
        params0.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);  // left, top, right, bottom
        relativelayout.addView(view0, params0);

        // horizontal line (button of screen)
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 5);
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, linearlayout.getId());
        relativelayout.addView(view3, params3);
    }
}
```

So it looks like when I add multiple `addRule()` to a param, it doesn't read both of them.  I think the problem lies in this line of the `topLeft()` method:  `params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view0.getId());`.  I've tried switching this line with the other addRule in that param and the result is the same.  Why is this?

**EDIT #1**
- Cleaned up my code to make neater and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are using params that require an anchor. You need to use "addRule (int verb, int anchor)"

so like

```
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,1);
```

Comment: Some `addRule()`s do not require an anchor.  The one you pointed out is working correctly and displaying the TextView with that param correctly.  I think the problem is in this line `params0.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view0.getId());` which is in the `topLeft()` method.

Comment: By the way, I edited the code in the opening post to make easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.  The error was in a part of my `onCreate()` method that I had not included in my opening post!  This was the problem code:

`view0.setId(0);`

Apparently the id cannot be set to 0.  Anyways, I changed the id number to a positive number and everything worked.